# Delphi Datasnap Server Memory Leak using TFileStream as returnvalue

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, zip, filestream, datasnap

i need a function in a datasnap-server, which returns a .zip file.
So i started with:

```
function TGetData.getZip (): TFileStream;
begin
   result := TFileStream.Create('test.zip', fmOpenRead and fmShareDenyWrite);
end
```

This works fine, but datasnap doesn't free it, so i get a memory leak error.

Next try:
I started at "TWebModule1.WebModuleAfterDispatch".
I thought it could help to send my response with "response.SendResponse;" and free my stream on my own. So here a short version:

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModuleAfterDispatch(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
var
   test : TFileStream;
begin
   response.ContentType := 'application/x-zip-compressed';
   test := TFileStream.Create('test.zip', fmOpenRead);
   response.ContentStream := test;
   response.CustomHeaders.Values['Content-Disposition'] := 'attachment; filename=test12.zip';
   response.SendResponse; //Also sendStream didn't help
   test.Free;
end;
```

This is nearly the solution i think, but the datasnap-server sends html-code after my stream was sent and this is written at the end of the file.

I know, the datasnap-server doenst support TFileStream. Instead i should use TDBXStreamValue, but there seems to be no working example...

Has any one expirience with such a problem?

Comment: What HTML is being written at the end of the file?

Comment: See [DataSnap Server Method Stream Parameters](http://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/datasnap-server-method-stream-parameters-31461).

Comment: the html part contains the response-informations like reposnse code (in example 200), the content type and so on.

Comment: That is not HTML, that is HTTP, and I find it very unlikely that such data would ever be getting written to the end of the file.  That would imply that DataSnap is not detecting that `SendResponse()` has already been called and is trying to send a second response. As for `TFileStream`, the documentation specifically states that a `TFileStream` can be used for the `ContentStream`, so why would you think it is not supported? Because it is not being freed? That would be a different bug. For instance, have you tried setting `response.FreeContentStream := true;` yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @remy lebeau

```
response.FreeContentStream := true;
```

this is the solution.

My function:

```
function TGetData.articleZippedImages(skip, take: Integer; since: string) : TStream;
```

the function does not free the stream!

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModuleAfterDispatch(Sender: TObject; Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
   response.FreeContentStream := true;
   Response.Content := '';
   Response.CustomHeaders.Values['Content-Disposition'] := 'attachment; filename=test.zip';
   Response.SendResponse;
end;
```